# Dict that converts list of lists month names

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Basically what I want to do is to convert some months names that are in romanian in the english names. I just want to convert only the index 4 position month in each list, the second one should stay the same, I will give you example:

I have this list of lists:

```
mylist = [[1,2,3,4,'Septembrie', 'August'], [1,2,3,4,'Martie', 'August'], [1,2,3,4,'Mai', 'August']]
```

And my desired output should be this:

```
mylist = [[1,2,3,4,'September', 'August'], [1,2,3,4,'March', 'August'], [1,2,3,4,'May', 'August']]
```

For the month August (on the index 5 position) I don't want to do any change, just leave it as it is!

I wrote this code:

```
conversionsEnNames = {"Ianuarie": "January", "Februarie": "February","Martie": "March", "Aprilie": "April","Mai": "May","Iunie": "June", "Iulie": "July","August": "August", "Septembrie": "September","Octombrie": "October", "Noiembrie": "November","Decembrie": "December"}

mylist = [[1,2,3,4,'Septembrie', 'August'], [1,2,3,4,'Martie', 'August'], [1,2,3,4,'Mai', 'August']]

for i in mylist:
    for j in i:
        if j in conversionsEnNames:
            j = conversionsEnNames[j]
            i[4]=j
```

But when I print mylist, it will output this:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 'August', 'August'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 'August', 'August'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 'August', 'August']]
```

But why? Cause I have declared `i[4]=j`, I'm a bit confused, so how I can achieve my desired output, and if possible I would prefer to work on the kinda same code structure I wrote, with a dict and for loop, thank you!! I use python 3.

Comment: You shouldn't edit lists the way you are doing, especially when you're iterating on them. The lists are generated using a generator function and modifying the list while it is still iterating can lead to all sorts of weird bugs.  If you want to modify like this, either refer to hspandher's answer or use numerical iteration (for i in range(len(list))

Comment: @NM I agree it can be dangerous to modify a list (or other collection) that you are iterating over. But that's mostly a problem if you add new items or remove old items, it's (usually) ok if you're merely changing the existing items. And you _can_ safely remove items from a list if you iterate over it in reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the dictionary to directly access the translations:

```
conversionsEnNames = {"Ianuarie": "January", "Februarie": "February","Martie": "March", "Aprilie": "April","Mai": "May","Iunie": "June", "Iulie": "July","August": "August", "Septembrie": "September","Octombrie": "October", "Noiembrie": "November","Decembrie": "December"}

mylist = [[1,2,3,4,'Septembrie', 'August'], [1,2,3,4,'Martie', 'August'], [1,2,3,4,'Mai', 'August']]

for i in mylist:
    month = i[4]
    if month in conversionsEnNames:
        i[4] = conversionsEnNames[month]

print(mylist)
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 'September', 'August'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 'March', 'August'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 'May', 'August']]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the name is found in names to be converted, replace them.

```
for value in mylist:
    if value[4] in conversionsEnNames:
        value[4] = conversionEnNames[value[4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can see why your code produces that output by adding a few `print` calls to your loops.

```
conversionsEnNames = {
    "Ianuarie": "January", "Februarie": "February", "Martie": "March",
    "Aprilie": "April", "Mai": "May", "Iunie": "June", "Iulie": "July",
    "August": "August", "Septembrie": "September", "Octombrie": "October",
    "Noiembrie": "November", "Decembrie": "December" 
}

mylist = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'Septembrie', 'August'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'Martie', 'August'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'Mai', 'August'],
]

print('Data:')
for row in mylist:
    print(row)
print()

for i in mylist:
    print('i:', i)
    for j in i:
        print(' old j:', j)
        if j in conversionsEnNames:
            j = conversionsEnNames[j]
            print(' new j:', j)
            i[4] = j
```

**output**

```
Data:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'Septembrie', 'August']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'Martie', 'August']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'Mai', 'August']

i: [1, 2, 3, 4, 'Septembrie', 'August']
 old j: 1
 old j: 2
 old j: 3
 old j: 4
 old j: Septembrie
 new j: September
 old j: August
 new j: August
i: [1, 2, 3, 4, 'Martie', 'August']
 old j: 1
 old j: 2
 old j: 3
 old j: 4
 old j: Martie
 new j: March
 old j: August
 new j: August
i: [1, 2, 3, 4, 'Mai', 'August']
 old j: 1
 old j: 2
 old j: 3
 old j: 4
 old j: Mai
 new j: May
 old j: August
 new j: August
```

So it *does* perform the desired translation, but then `i[4]` gets overwritten by the translation of `i[5]`.

---

Here's a modified version of your code that does what you want. Rather than using `if` to test if a key is in the translation dictionary we use the `get` method, and tell it to return the key if the key isn't in the dictionary.

```
english_months = {
    "Ianuarie": "January", "Februarie": "February", "Martie": "March",
    "Aprilie": "April", "Mai": "May", "Iunie": "June", "Iulie": "July",
    "August": "August", "Septembrie": "September", "Octombrie": "October",
    "Noiembrie": "November", "Decembrie": "December" 
}

mylist = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'Septembrie', 'August'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'Martie', 'August'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'Mai', 'August'],
]

print('Original:')
for row in mylist:
    print(row)
print()

for row in mylist:
    month = row[4]
    row[4] = english_months.get(month, month)

print('Translated:')
for row in mylist:
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
Original:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'Septembrie', 'August']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'Martie', 'August']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'Mai', 'August']

Translated:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'September', 'August']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'March', 'August']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'May', 'August']
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

If the `name` in each sublist remains at index 4:

```
for l in mylst: // iterate through list sublists [[sublist1], [sublist2], ... ]
    if l[4] in conversionsEnNames: // check if key exists in dict
        l[4] = conversionsEnNames[l[4]] // supply value of key to sublist index 4
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want answer in your way you could just simply add break at last because after executing if block it also checks for the last element.And in dictionary "August" key is already there without any difference

```
conversionsEnNames = {"Ianuarie": "January", "Februarie": "February","Martie": "March", "Aprilie": "April","Mai": "May","Iunie": "June", "Iulie": "July","August": "August", "Septembrie": "September","Octombrie": "October", "Noiembrie": "November","Decembrie": "December"}

mylist = [[1,2,3,4,'Septembrie', 'August'], [1,2,3,4,'Martie', 'August'], [1,2,3,4,'Mai', 'August']]

for i in mylist:
    for j in i:
        if j in conversionsEnNames:
            j = conversionsEnNames[j]
            i[4]=j
            break
```

Comment: While functional, this answer does not use the `dict` class in the manner that it was designed.

Comment: ya exactly.Thats why I have mentioned if he wants the answer in his way. :)